# Is this graph of $f(x)=\frac{1}{\left [ \frac{1}{x} \right ]}$ present in Spivak's Calculus correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, graphing-functions

The following problem is from Ch. 4 "Graphs" from Spivak's *Calculus*

> 17. The symbol $[x]$ denotes the largest integer which is $\leq x$. Thus, $[2.1]=[2]=2$ and $[-0.9]=[-1]=-1$. Draw the graph of the
>     following functions (they are all quite interesting, and several will
>     reappear frequently in other problems).
>
> (vi) $f(x)=\frac{1}{\left [ \frac{1}{x} \right ]}$

The solution manual solution for this particular item is

[image]

**Is this actually correct for values of $x\leq 0$?**

For example consider the interval $[-1/2,-1/3]$. The graph above seems to imply that for any $x \in (-1/2,-1/3)$, we have $f(x)=f(-1/2)$.

But consider one such value, for example $-0.4=-\frac{2}{5}$. Then

$$\left [ \frac{1}{-2/5} \right ]= \left [ -\frac{5}{2} \right ]= [-2.5]=-3$$

Hence

$$f(-2/5)= -\frac{1}{3}=f(-1/3)$$

Second of all, why is the function not defined for $x\leq -1$?

For example,

$$f(-2)=\frac{1}{\left [ \frac{1}{-2} \right ]}=\frac{1}{-1}=-1$$

$$f(-1000)=\frac{1}{\left [ \frac{1}{-1000} \right ]}=\frac{1}{-1}=-1$$

Shouldn't the graph look like

[image]

EDIT:

Note that the solution manual also has the following graph

[image]

for the function

$$f(x)=\left [ \frac{1}{x} \right ]$$

which also seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Does the solution manual include any markings on the axes so one could read values?

Comment: The solution manual is wrong.

Comment: @coffeemath no markings no

Comment: I've added another (simpler) function and graph from the same problem in Spivak that also seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @evianpring The simpler graph of floor(1/x) is also wrong in Spivak. The filled in holes should be on the right of each solid part, not the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch!

It seems that the author is using the *integer part* function $\operatorname{int}(x)$ which always rounds towards zero rather than the *floor* function $\lfloor x \rfloor$ which always rounds down. They agree for all $x \geq 0$, but for $x < 0$,
$$
\operatorname{int}(x) = \lceil x \rceil = - \lfloor -x \rfloor
$$
If $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$ and $x<0$, the difference is precisely one:
$$
\operatorname{int}(x) = 1 + \lfloor x \rfloor, 
$$
but the two functions do agree at all integer values.

Another distinction, which is visible in the graphs: the floor function, is always continuous from the right
$$
\lim_{x \to a^+} \lfloor x \rfloor = \lfloor a \rfloor, 
$$
whereas the integer part function is always continuous from the direction away from zero. Hence, for $a<0$,
$$
\lim_{x \to a^-} \operatorname{int}(x) = \operatorname{int}(a). 
$$

You can compare them [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sbsr6gznvm) by clicking on one or the other folder to toggle the graphs on/off.